# Use Packer AND YUI Compressor?

Tags: yui-compressor, packer

I've been looking for a way to easily compress my .js locally before deployment. I finally found a command line batch script that works with YUICompressor and Packer.

The problem I was having was that Packer was corrupting my files. Figuring it was an older version, I just manually took my YUIcompressed .js and ran it through the online Packer.

The result is that PACKER only reduces my YUIcompressed ..js by about 1%. Hardly worth the effort, it seems.

That said, I don't know much about Packer. Doing some research, it seems that YUICompressor and Packer are really both separate .js compressors. Is there really a need to use both? Do people use both? If so, why? Does Packer do something above and beyond compression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packer is not recommended. It takes time for the client to unpack, erasing all gains from the smaller file size. I don't think there is any reason to use it.

YUICompressor is very good and using it alone is sufficient.

Comment: That pretty much confirms my experience thus far. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget, there's a .NET port of YUICompressor found [here on codeplex](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/), called YUICompressor for .NET. That might also help...

*Disclaimer: I made most of that port.